# Generate index information for a runnable jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I'm having trouble adding index information to a runnable jar, it always gives me the following (misleading) error:

```
jar i mainapp.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: . (Access is denied)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.getJarPath(Main.java:1052)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.getJarPath(Main.java:1068)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.genIndex(Main.java:1084)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:269)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

(no file lock exists on file)

I use eclipse kepler (can't upgrade for this project) to generate the runnable jar. The jar starts and runs without problems.

Now due to external requirements ( don't ask ;-) ) i have to add index information to my runnable jar, so i call:

```
jar i mainapp.jar
```

i:

```
-i  generate index information for the specified jar files
```

The jar command prints above exception. When i just export a normal jar from my eclipse the jar -i command works and a INDEX.LIST is added to META-INF folder in jar.

Isn't it possible to generate index information for a runnable jar?

(note that i cannot switch/upgrade ide's or build systems, i'm required to generate the runnable jar with eclipse kepler, although i can do whatever i want with the generated jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I ended up exporting normal jar from eclipse, generating index info with 'jar' and manually adding runnable info to the jar manifest.